# How to interrupt new page insertion using column_boxes in Prawn

Tags: prawn

I override `#start_new_page` in my Prawn class with some logic that adds borders to the page as the last thing during page creation. I am now adding some pages that use `#column_boxes`. Unfortunately, overflow pages don't seem to trigger `#start_new_page`.

I added this:

```
current_page_count = page_count

# write some text page(s)...

new_page_count = page_count

(new_page_count - current_page_count).times do |additional_index|
  # pages are 1-based, but #times yields a zero-based value
  next_page = current_page_count + additional_index + 1

  go_to_page next_page
  add_border
end
```

Unfortunately, The border is now placed over top of the content, rather than behind it. Is there a way I can either:

- add my border before `#column_boxes` renders content to the new page
- or
- merge two pages

I would be okay with creating a new page with just a border, then merging the content from the one `#column_boxes` created over top of it.

I realize I could do the merging in Ghostscript, but it has to be done within Prawn, because I create an unknown amount of content based on user data.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason the code was broken is I had changed to including `Prawn::View` at the same time. My `#start_new_page` override stopped working because of that. I switched back to inheriting and it works now.